# Loading markers on google map showing address and restaurant name

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift2, marker

Here is my code. The issue is with loading time. It takes long time to load markers and sometimes does not load any marker.

```
     for dict in json as! [NSDictionary]{
                        self.names.append(dict["name"] as! String)
                        self.address.append(dict["address"] as! String)



                 //For Loop

                        //for googleadd in self.address {
                            for googleadd in self.address {
                                let annotationTitle: String = googleadd

                            // to display restaurant name
                           for googlename in self.names {
                                let annotationTitle: String = googlename;

                            var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(googleadd, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark? {
//                                    print("PlaceMark:: \(placemark)")
                                    if placemark == nil{
                                        return
                                    }


                                        if let coordinate = placemark?.location?.coordinate {
//                                        print("placemark::\(placemark) coordinate::\(coordinate)");
                                        let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()


                                       anotation.coordinate = coordinate



                                           anotation.title = googlename



                                       anotation.subtitle = googleadd
                                        //    anotation.title = googleadd
                                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)
                                        self.mapView.setCenterCoordinate(coordinate, zoomLevel: 12, animated: true)


                                            // Add a detail disclosure button to the callout.

                                         /*   let button : UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
                                            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                                            anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView=button

                                    */
                                    }


                                   // self.mapView.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark!))
                                }
                            })

                              //  print(googlename)
                           } // googlename loop ends here

                        }
}
```

Comment: If the geocoded doesn't find the address you will not see the placemark (can easily debug this). Also if you have a large amount of addresses, it may take a while to translate them all.

Comment: but I am getting addresses and names on console and there are around 40 to 50 addresses.

Comment: @SallyPeter I may be wrong but you appear to be using an `MKMapView` from Apple Maps rather than a `GMSMapView` from the Google Maps SDK. If this is the case, your question is confusing due to the misleading terms.